# boost::make_shared causes access violation

Tags: c++, boost, windows-mobile

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application for ARMV4I Windows Mobile 6 where I'm using `boost::shared_ptr<>` to manage a fairly large object (4KB). Unfortunately, `boost::make_shared<>` causes an Access Violation exception.

My code:

```
struct Foo
{
    char a[ 4 * 1024 - 1 ];
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< Foo > f = boost::make_shared< Foo >(); // Access Violation
    return 0;
}
```

The exception callstack:

```
test.exe!boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<o>::sp_ms_deleter<o>(void) Line: 60, Byte Offsets: 0x18   C++
test.exe!boost::make_shared<o>(void) Line: 106, Byte Offsets: 0x5c  C++
test.exe!wmain(int argc = 1, wchar_t** argv = 0x01b40060) Line: 81, Byte Offsets: 0x18  C++
test.exe!mainWCRTStartup(HINSTANCE__* hInstance = 0x00000003, HINSTANCE__* hInstancePrev = 0x00000000, unsigned short* lpszCmdLine = 0x00000003, int nCmdShow = 0) Line: 188, Byte Offsets: 0x94    C++
```

The location of the exception (boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp):

```
template< class T > class sp_ms_deleter
{
    /* snip! */        
public:
    sp_ms_deleter(): initialized_( false )
    {    // line: 60  this = NULL
    }

    /* snip! */
```

This issue does not occur when compiling for x86 Windows. This issue also does not occur when using the shared_ptr like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr< Foo > f1 = boost::shared_ptr< Foo >( new Foo );
```

Can anybody explain what's going on and why this is breaking only on ARMV4I Windows Mobile 6?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: @ildjarn - 1.45.0 with STLPort 5.2.1

Comment: This looks like it might be a platform specific boost/smart pointers bug; presumably because of some sort of complication of allocating a large structure on ARM. I'd suggest posting this to the mailing list.

Comment: @PaulH : Any chance you can test with Boost 1.46.1, just in case it was a bug fixed since 1.45.0? If it's indeed a bug in Boost, then I strongly suspect `boost::alignment_of<>` or `boost::type_with_alignment<>` to be the culprits.

Comment: @Autopulated : My suspicion is that `sp_ms_deleter` (or its subobjects) isn't being aligned correctly moreso than that it is too large.

Comment: @ildjarn - I haven't seen shared_ptr on the list of updates for 1.46.0 or 1.46.1 so I assume nothing's changed. Do they include changes not listed on the NEWS section of the boost.org homepage?

Comment: @PaulH : I doubt `shared_ptr` itself is at fault, more likely the Boost.TypeTraits library is at fault here, and it's been updated every release since VC++ 2010 was released.

Comment: @ildjarn - boost 1.46.1 has the same behavior.

Comment: @PaulH : Fair enough; time to take it to the [Boost User's ML](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-users) in my opinion.

Comment: @all - it is posted to the boost-user's ML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a stack overflow issue. This was already reported in [ticket #4256](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4256). Upgrading to the tips fixes it, so it should be available in the next Boost update.

Thanks to [Peter Dimov in the Boost Users ML](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/shared-ptr-make-shared-causes-Access-Violation-td3512891.html).

Answer (score 4):

Probably it's an alignment issue. I don't know the details of the implementation, but `make_shared<>()` tries to allocate the `shared_ptr<>` object and the pointed-to object in one single allocation. Probably this causes one of the two objects to end up at an address that isn't aligned as it should be.

This would explain why it only crashes on ARM: That architecture has stricter alignment requirements than normal PC hardware. If an int or a pointer ends up on a "strange" address, your program will crash on ARM while your PC does happily  access the data.